# Split column to multiple columns adaptively in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
Name    Value
abc     Asia
def     Asia/Africa
gbc     Africa
jhg     America/Africa/Asia
```

I want the column Value to be separated so that the dataframe looks as follows:

```
Name    Value.1    Value.2    Value.3
abc     Asia 
def     Asia       Africa
gbc     Africa
jhg     America    Africa    Asia
```

I know there are similar questions on stackoverflow (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069076/split-column-at-delimiter-in-data-frame), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350440/split-a-column-of-a-data-frame-to-multiple-columns) ) but they assume that *Value* can be split into the same number of sections for each row. So, when I try to run the following commands:

```
out <- strsplit(as.character(df$Value),'/')
do.call(rbind, out)
data.frame(df$Value, do.call(rbind, out))
```

It works till the second line and then gives me the following error:

```
Error in data.frame(df$Value, do.call(rbind,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 24819, 24707
In addition: Warning message:
In (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 10)
```

I also looked into reshape2 function [colSplit](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/) and tidyr function [separate](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/reshape2/docs/colsplit). They also expect that for every row, *Value* can be seperated into exactly the same number of components, hence they expect me to name the columns in advance.

I am wondering of there is a way to adaptively name split the *Value* into separate columns called *Value.1*, *Value.2*,...

Comment: Your question is better since you include an example, but I guess this one also covers it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26898833/1191259

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In base R:

```
df <- read.table(textConnection("Name    Value
abc     Asia
def     Asia/Africa
gbc     Africa
jhg     America/Africa/Asia"), header=TRUE)

out <- strsplit(as.character(df$Value),'/')
out <- lapply(out, FUN=function(x) c(unlist(x), rep(NA, max(lengths(out))-length(x))))
out <- as.data.frame( cbind(df$Value,do.call(rbind, out)))

  V1      V2     V3   V4
1  3    Asia   <NA> <NA>
2  4    Asia Africa <NA>
3  1  Africa   <NA> <NA>
4  2 America Africa Asia
```

Same approach, written a bit different:

```
out <- strsplit(as.character(df$Value),'/')
cbind(df[1], do.call(rbind, lapply(out, 'length<-', max(lengths(out)))))
  Name       1      2    3
1  abc    Asia   <NA> <NA>
2  def    Asia Africa <NA>
3  gbc  Africa   <NA> <NA>
4  jhg America Africa Asia
```

Comment: You can use `max(lengths(out))` as max length after the `strsplit`

Comment: Thanks @docendodiscimus

Comment: Welcome. Another trick is to use `lapply(out, 'length<-', max(lengths(out)))` which will populate shorter vectors with NAs

Comment: @docendodiscimus Great! But how can I write ` on SO?

Comment: Do you mean inside comments? I don't know that but in normal posts it's not a problem. And my comment also works with normal '

Comment: @HubertL are you trying insert docendo's code in your answer?

Comment: Hubert, I made an edit to your answer. Feel free to rollback or re-edit of course

Comment: Fyi, backticks in comment code work if you escape them with a backslash @docendo

Comment: Thanks @Frank, that's nice to know

Answer (score 4):

We can use `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df1, 'Value', '/', 'wide')
#   Name Value_1 Value_2 Value_3
#1:  abc    Asia      NA      NA
#2:  def    Asia  Africa      NA
#3:  gbc  Africa      NA      NA
#4:  jhg America  Africa    Asia
```

---

In `base R`, we could simply do

```
cbind(df1[1],read.table(text=df1$Value, sep='/', fill=TRUE))
#  Name      V1     V2   V3
#1  abc    Asia            
#2  def    Asia Africa     
#3  gbc  Africa            
#4  jhg America Africa Asia
```

Answer (score 4):

See `tstrsplit` in `data.table` which automatically fills out ragged splits (with `NA` by default, but can be controlled with the `fill` argument):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[ , tstrsplit(Value, split = "/")]
```

If you wanted to add these as columns to your data, it's a bit uglier to do dynamically

```
setDT(df1)[ , paste0("V", 1:max(sapply(spl <- strsplit(x, "/"), length))) := 
              transpose(spl)]
```